# Make key codes same

Tags: java, key, awt, awtrobot

I need to make it so using `Robot.keyPress(keycode)` will press the correct key that was pressed on a different computer/keyboard.

Right now, pressing '/' will give me a key code that would press (using robot) ';' on a different computer. I'm using `getKeyCode()` from KeyEvent to get the keycode.

Literally the only code I'm using is `Robot.keyPress()` and `KeyEvent.getKeyCode()`.

So how can I make the robot press the right key?

Comment: do i understand you right: you are not interested in a certain key_code to be pressed rather you like to ensure to be the same button be pressed (maybe upper row, second from left = F1 on my keyboard)?